# MS Photos will not make video

Tags: microsoft-office, photos, animation

I need to make an animation for a presentation.

MS Photos should be able to [make videos](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17205/windows-10-create-videos) but the buttons that are needed for this capability just don't show up in my copy of Photos.  The version I am running is supposedly the latest and greatest.  Has anybody seen this problem?  I suspect that either this option is not available until I open an MS account, or else my organization has curmudgeonly installed Photos without this capability.  Are either of these possible or likely?

(BTW, someone's edit to my question changed not just my casual grammar, but the actual meaning of the question.  I have re-edited.)

Comment: Click on _Create > Video remix_ and select the photos and videos you want to include.. Select Remix it for me  to instantly change its look and feel by recombining images, music, and styles. And, if you go to Apps and Features after right-clicking on the START button of Windows, you can find the version of Microsoft Photos so you can tell us which you have.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no "video remix" option under "create".

Comment: They you don't have the current version. Please contact your IT folks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing the answer to share what I get on my computer:
My Microsoft Photos version is 2020.19111.22010.0. I can use it to create a video:

[image]

[image]

When I first clicked New video button, Microsoft Photo stopped and then a new add-on called "Photos Media Engine Add-on" was installed:

[image]

After it's installed successfully, Microsoft Photos restarted:

[image]

You can try to [Repair or Reset the app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028054/windows-10-repair-or-remove-programs) to have a check:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  Unfortunately, I am seeing pretty much none of the buttons you are showing.  Even from the start, I don't have "new video".  And it turns out that my version is 2018.18051.21218.0, so I guess they didn't give me the latest and greatest after all.  Any idea when videos were added to MS Photos?  Thanks again.  I do appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you need to contact your administrator/IT pro to get help. Some settings/ policies are not easy to change.